# Plot pandas dataframe with defined ticks (conversion to datetime)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to plot a pandas dateframe with defined ticks.

[image]

As it can be seen in the plot the time distance between ticks is 8 minutes and 20 seconds. I would like to have this in 5 Minute steps.

The data is a dataframe with the following structure:

```
                           Data1      Data2       
timestamps                                                                                                                       
0 days 00:00:00         36.59338  36.465206  
0 days 00:00:00.100000  36.59338  36.465206  
0 days 00:00:00.200000  36.59338  36.465206  
0 days 00:00:00.300000  36.59338  36.465206  
0 days 00:00:00.400000  36.59338  36.465206
```

How can I control the step size of the ticks in the example?

The code:

```
df.plot(color=colors);
```

Leads to the above Picture.

Answer (score 1):

`df.plot()` fortunately returns a `matplotlib.AxesSubplot` so you can change paramaters as you would usually do. Also, to properly define datetime xticks, you should use the `matplotlib.dates` package.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
ax = df.plot(color=colors)
min_time = df.index.minute.min
max_time = df.index.minute.max
time_int = 5
xlocator = md.MinuteLocator(byminute=np.arange(min_time, max_time+1, time_int), interval = 1)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xlocator)
```

Comment: This looks good. Unfortuantely I get the error:
AttributeError: 'TimedeltaIndex' object has no attribute 'minute'